# Memory management for a custom class performing network asynchronous requests

Tags: ios, memory-management, asynchronous, automatic-ref-counting, nsurlconnection

I've implemented a class where I encapsulate an asynchronous request with `NSURLConnection` and its delegate methods stuff. I create an instance of this class in a view controller whenever a button of its view is tapped, and I ask it for making the network request:

```
- (IBAction)getData:(id)sender
{
   // Perform network request
   Updater *updater = [[Updater alloc] init];
   [updater queryService:self.date];
}
```

Such `queryService:` method is like this:

```
- (void)queryService:(NSDate *)date
{
   self.responseData = [NSMutableData data];

   NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:kTimeout];
   NSURLConnection *connection = [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:self];
}
```

Since `Updater` is performing an asynchronous operation, I'm not sure if the `updater` instance, which I've declared as local variable, will be retained until `connection:didFailWithError:` or `connectionDidFinishLoading:` are called, or I'd create a `strong` property for the `Updater` in the calling view controller. I'm using ARC.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it will be retained until the connection ends (fail, success ecc).
It happens because your Updater instance is the delegate of `NSURLConnection`.

Inside `NSURLConnection` doc you can read:

> Note: During a download the connection maintains a strong reference to the delegate. It releases that strong reference when the connection finishes loading, fails, or is canceled.

Answer (score -1):

You need a strong reference, could be' an ivar to Update or an ivar to a collection with update instances. Even if the delegate is retained you did not explain how you get data back.